# Applications of context free grammars in real life?

Tags: context-free-grammar, dfa

What are the applications of context free grammars in real life?
Whatt are the applications of DFA and CFG?

Answer (score 2):

Context-free grammars are used in compilers and in particular for *parsing*, taking a string-based program and figuring out what it means. Typically, CFGs are used to define the high-level structure of a programming language. Figuring out how a particular string was derived tells us about its structure and meaning. These [course notes](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs143/cs143.1128/lectures/02/Slides02.pdf) give a good overview of this idea.

Finite state machines such as DFAs are used to model the behavior of everyday objects and processes such as circuits and network protocols. One example of this is [a standard HTML button](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs103/cs103.1142/button-fsm/).

You may also be interested in this [related question on cs.stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/85913/what-are-applications-of-the-levels-of-the-chomsky-hierarchy/).